# How to add a top level router outlet in Angular

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

This is probably really easy, but for some reason I just can't get to figure it out. I have some html in my app component:

```
<div class="top-half">
    <app-top-bar></app-top-bar>
</div>

<div class="bottom-half">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is cool, but I can't figure a way to display a whole new page, login page for example, without having all the persistent elements (top-bar, side-bar, etc...). Is there a way to have some sort of a "outer level" router outlet to control the navigation between the pages.
Thank you in advance

Edit, here is the router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'boards', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'boards', component: BoardComponent },
  { path: 'boards/:boardId', component: BoardComponent },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I don't think if I truly understand what you mean, I have two different thoughts about what you said. But aside, what you want is a complete new page, right? If so, just create a different path outside of that `children` array on `app-routing`

Comment: I think this wont work @manjirosano because with the <router-outlet> you only update that part of the page, so if you load any component, the top and the side components will remain there

Comment: He wants to create a whole different, blank page. `router-outlet` will only display the `children` paths of that route, not the whole routing paths. I'd like to see how his `app-routing.module.ts` is.

Comment: Maybe I am explaining myself wrongly, I assume that the code that he displayed, is from a path, where it is part of a path `children`. I really need the `app-routing.module.ts` to analyze better what's going on.

Comment: @manjirosano, aight, so, the app is some sort of a Kanban Board. Router outlet displays a different board, based on some id

Comment: @manjirosano 
`const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'boards', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'boards', component: BoardComponent },
  { path: 'boards/:boardId', component: BoardComponent },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }`

Comment: Can you edit your post, with the `app-routing` code, and say where you currently are (on the side of the path, saying where u are)

Comment: @VictorZlatin, add the code into your question, please

Comment: @manjirosano, what I want to do, is to create a route to a login page, that won't show the sidebar and other stuff that's always there, regardless of what board is displayed

Comment: the `html` code, is from which route? where you currently are, in the `html` code

Comment: @AhmedSHA256, you got it correctly, that's exactly the problem I'm trying to address

Comment: @manjirosano, I'm not sure I'm following. That's the app component's html

Comment: Okay, I believe all you need to do, is move all that code to the component `BoardComponent` and leave only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html`.

Comment: @VictorZlatin, I know it was easy.. I just need context to know how ur routing system is, and your current location, and everything will be easy. Im glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

Let suppose you have your router-outlet in **app.component.html**

```html
<div class="top-half">
    <app-top-bar></app-top-bar>
</div>

<div class="bottom-half">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In the app.component.ts file,make a getter for accessing the current route in real time using the below code snippet.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
  
   get getCurrentURL() {
    return this.router.url;
  }
}
```

Then apply the logic in **app.component.html** to show and hide the **Navbar** and **Sidebar**

```html
<div class="top-half"  *ngIf="!getCurrentURL.includes('/login')">
      <app-top-bar></app-top-bar>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottom-half" *ngIf="!getCurrentURL.includes('/login')">
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

It will not render navbar and sidebar when the **/login** route is active.
*Note: The entire implementation has nothing to do with protecting routes.*

Comment: That's dope, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can also to have nested `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Imagine your app.component is like

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And have a main.component in the way

```
<nav>
    Your navigation
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>The footer</footer>
```

You can have a routes defined in the way:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  { path: 'no-login', component: NoLoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',                     //see the path:''
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'boards', component: BoardsComponent },
      { path: 'boards/:boardId', component: BoardComponent },
      { path: 'anothers', component: AnothersComponent },
      { path: 'anothers/:boardId', component: AnotherComponent },
      {
        path: '',                //see how we force that if path=''
        redirectTo: '/boards',   //redirect to board
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      //instead of redirect you can also to have
      //{ path: '', component: DefaultComponent}
      //and path='' show the <nav></nav>
      //                        <default-component>
      //                     <footer>
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/boards',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];
```

I put the example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ugxf8g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts)

See that, e.g. if you navigate to board really you has in your .html some like(*)

```
<my-app>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-main _nghost-btb-c57="">
      <nav>...your navigation..</nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          <app-boards></app-boards>
      <footer>..the footer..</footer>
  </app-main>
</my-app>
```

(*)Understand that the  only indicate where are this

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. I went with a simpler solution, due to the simple nature of the app, but this is cool.